# "Pip install spacy" fails with an error

Tags: python, pip, spacy

"Pip install spacy" fails with the cryptic error below and I have no idea how to handle it. Has anybody seen an issue like this before

```
Command "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-9vm71w85/spacy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-cpqq4x9o/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code -9 in /tmp/pip-install-9vm71w85/spacy/
```

Comment: are you installing pip using get-pip.py script?

Comment: question updated.

Comment: try `pip install -U spacy`

Comment: Is there any other output, or just that error? Are you having the same problem with any other packages?